# Reference class method from class var

Tags: python

I need to build a dict mapping integers to functions. the functions are class methods, and the dict itself is a class variable. both the functions and the dict are members of the same class.

The problem boils down to the fact, that i seem to be unable to reference a class variable from another class variable. The error i get can be reproduced by executing the following piece of code:

```
class MyClass():

    @classmethod
    def myClassMethod(cls):
        pass

    myClassVar = MyClass.myClassMethod


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyClass.myClassVar()
```

which yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cvartest.py", line 2, in <module>
    class MyClass():
  File "cvartest.py", line 8, in MyClass
    myClassVar = MyClass.myClassMethod
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

how could i solve my problem?

Comment: Why do you need two names referring to the same method?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `class`:

```
class MyClass():

    @classmethod
    def myClassMethod(cls):
        pass

    myClassVar = myClassMethod


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyClass.myClassVar()
```

Why or whether you ought to do this I won't comment on